# (How) should redacted years be read aloud?

Tags: pronunciation, dates

Related to but different from [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9479/) question about the purpose of such redactions.

How should a passage such as this from Mary Shelley's *Frankenstein* be read aloud?

> St. Petersburgh, Dec. 11th, 17--

I have listened to a few audiobook excerpts and they differ on the convention: they may [say "seventeen blank blank"](https://youtu.be/MZfXP2YZqEk?t=291) or simply [omit the year entirely](https://youtu.be/AmUuXtVWZb4?t=14). Omission is a reasonable option for the header of a letter, which is the context of this line.

However, what about this sentence from Thomas Mann's *Death in Venice* as translated by Michael Henry Heim?

> Gustav Aschenbach or von Aschenbach, as he had officially been known since his fiftieth birthday, set out alone from his residence in Munich’s Prinzregentenstrasse on a spring afternoon in 19.. — a year that for months had shown so ominous a countenance to our continent — with the intention of taking an extended walk.

The sentence doesn't make sense if "19.." is omitted. The audiobook I was able to hear a sample of used a different translation that doesn't include any mention of the year at all. How would "19.." be pronounced?

Comment: Fake it.   Or read "dash-dash".

Comment: It would be nice if someone had done a bit of research by listening to a sample of audiobooks and reporting here how the question posed had been dealt with. I have no audiobooks and cannot therefore do that research, but without it a good answer is impossible.

Comment: The first one I might read as "December 11th in a year late in the 18th century".

Comment: I would probably read '17--' it as 'seventeen something'.

Answer (score -1):

In the first case I'd improvise and say "Dec. 11th  in a year not mentioned of the eighteenth century". I'd do similarly for the second one.